# Get next recurrence of a Later schedule

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using `later.js` in order to create a simple schedule. I am trying to back this up with a mongo database for persistence.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  const current = Schedule.findOne({ name: 'send text reminders' });
  const interval = current.interval || 1;

  const recurrence = Later.parse.recur().every(interval).minute();

  Later.setInterval(function sendReminders() {
    Schedule.update({
      name: 'send text reminders'
    }, {
      $set: {
        nextRunAt: // get the next scheduled time.
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I've been looking through the docs but haven't found an area where they say how to get the *next* occurence of a schedule.

Is it possible to get the next scheduled run with `later.js`?